# Google analytics using REST api

Tags: google-analytics

I want to add Google analytics manually on each pages and events in my website. Is there any ways to add Google analytics using REST api or any library in PHP. so i can track specific events of my website.

Answer (score 0):

There is no REST API for Google Analytics. You will have to use one of the available libraries provided by Google.

To track particular events, you can use tag manager or simply use custom dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR, Google Analytics is great if all you ever use is their GUI dashboard. If you need API access, go with another service.

---

If you need to access analytics data programmatically, especially if you are using NodeJS, I suggest you use some other service besides Google. Their documentation is incredibly lacking, they try to pigeon-hole you into using a client library rather than steering you in the direction of a REST API, and authenticating is a nightmare. The new v4 API purportedly consists of a single endpoint that you need to query with a complex combination of HTTP body and query params. Again, documentation is nearly non-existent.